# Ubuntu crashes when "Login as another user" is selected

Tags: login

Here is the sequence of events. The computer is turned on, and User A logs on to Ubuntu. After some period of time the screen saver kicks in. User B comes along and selects "Login as another user" from the locked screen. Ubuntu immediately crashes and displays this screen (see screen photo below). At this point the computer is totally locked up does not respond to input from the keyboard or mouse.

[image]

I installed Ubuntu a couple of weeks ago, so it is relatively new. The problem described above happens about half of the time, and other times when "Login as another user" is selected it works just fine.

Here are the contents of /var/log/syslog from the time of the crash...

`Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (**) Option "fd" "21"
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop kernel: [48471.682629] rfkill: input handler enabled
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop kernel: [48471.791031] show_signal_msg: 27 callbacks suppressed
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop kernel: [48471.791034] gnome-shell[927]: segfault at 91 ip 0000000000000091 sp 00007ffd59787138 error 14
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop kernel: [48471.791038] Code: Bad RIP value.
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop gsd-color[1140]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/home/rgoscar/.local/share/icc/edid-91a77f3fba628619db71e250f829f8d8.icc”: Permission denied
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (**) Option "fd" "24"
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) event4  - Video Bus: device removed
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (**) Option "fd" "25"
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (**) Option "fd" "26"
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) event2  - Dell Dell Smart Card Reader Keyboard: device removed
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (**) Option "fd" "27"
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) event3  - Logitech M325: device removed
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (**) Option "fd" "28"
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (**) Option "fd" "28"
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) event14 - Hauppauge WinTV-dualHD 01595 ATSC/QAM: device removed
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:78
Mar  3 20:34:31 rgoscar-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1309]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop gnome-session[909]: gnome-session-binary[909]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[927]: (EE)
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[927]: Fatal server error:
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[927]: (EE) failed to read Wayland events: Broken pipe
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[927]: (EE)
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop gnome-session-binary[909]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop gnome-session-binary[909]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop gsd-power[1156]: Error setting property 'PowerSaveMode' on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying (g-dbus-error-quark, 4)
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop gsd-color[1594]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_ViewSonic_Corporation_VE710b_2_P1Q042101664_gdm_121
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop at-spi-bus-launcher[1081]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1024"
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop at-spi-bus-launcher[1081]:       after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 121...
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopping sandboxed app permission store...
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopping Sound Service...
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped target Default.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped sandboxed app permission store.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped Sound Service.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped target Paths.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped target Sockets.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Stopped target Timers.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Closed Sound System.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Starting Exit the Session...
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[887]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 4708 (kill).
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 121.
Mar  3 20:34:32 rgoscar-desktop systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of gdm.`

Comment: Developers who created the feature expected "Login as another user" to work ALL the time. You seem to have discovered a bug. If this is an older release of Ubuntu (like 18.04), please see if the problem occurs in the newest release (19.10). If you can still make login-switching fail half the time on 19.10, then please file a bug report.

Comment: For the actual question you asked "Why?" note the exact time of a freeze. Wait a few minutes in case the system unfreezes on it's own. Reboot (only if necessary). Then check /var/log/syslog for events logged at that time. Also check /var/crash for .crash files created around that time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, user535733. I was not aware of the technique to check /var/log/syslog. I will do that! Will also check exactly which Ubuntu version I have and file a bug report if necessary.

Comment: I was able to recreate the event last night, and the contents of /var/log/syslog around the time of the crash are pasted below.  I did not see any .crash files from the same time.  Actually, it won't let me paste the contents of /var/log/syslog here...says it is too long.

Comment: I pasted the contents of /var/log/syslog to the original question.

Comment: Display server crash, perhaps gnome-shell crash, cause indeterminate from syslog. This sort of crash usually generates a .crash file. If this crash persists in 19.10, then file a bug, and attach the .crash report. Really not much you can do beyond that.

Comment: Try to get into your grub menu and start your linux with 'acpi=off' set on start

Answer (score 0):

Install the `lightdm` package and that will resolve the problem.

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Comment: Thanks...I will look into this `lightdm` package!